# javascript problem related to pop window

Tags: javascript, popup, window.onunload

I need a pop window which could not be refreshed by user. for that i am trying this:

```
function openNewWindow(href){
        alert("hello here");
        var newWindow = window.open(href, 'newWindow', 
        'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,resizable=no,width=1024,height=400');
        return false;
    }

<a onclick="return openNewWindow(this.href);" href="newPage.html" >Click me</a>
```

newPage.html

```
window.onunload = check;
    function check(){
        alert("hey");
        return false;
    }
```

Here alert is generated when i try to reload the browser. but `return false;` is not working.

Or if it is possible to not to have `Navigation bar` in newly pop up window.

So please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> newWindow.onload = setUnloadHandler;

It's not clear from your example, but probably `newWindow` contains a document from another site. You can't script into it due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Also, browsers won't let you do anything to prevent an unloading in the `onunload` handler, because it's obnoxious and users hate it—remember the old days when this was allowed, and abused to generate endless uncloseable porn popup loops?

You can't get an unrefreshable window. What is your purpose in trying to do so?

Comment: i am conducting an online exam and in this there is a timer. i want this timer should not be restarted from begin. because this will give the user more time. and it is not right.

Comment: Hey can you please check out my edited question. as the newwindow contains the page from same site and i have edited the code of `newPage.html` to have unload handler.